# Sorting alphabetically - best intuitive way to signify alphabetical ordering

Tags: ordering, order, intuitive

So I have a plain old button (two buttons to be exact). The button reads "SORT", when you click the button, an option comes up and lets you choose a sort type.

I have two types of sorting: price and alphabetical.

For price, I decided to use font-size to designate ascending/descending order.

Something like this:

```
<span style='font-size:x-large'>$</span>
<span 'font-size:medium'>$</span>
<span 'font-size:small'>$</span>
```

This does not directly use the word "Price" but signifies order and variable. I currently use text for alphabetical ordering, but would want to switch to a symbolic approach like: a-Z or Z-a to signify alphabetical ordering.

So, my question is what is the BEST way to signify alphabetical order?

[image: My own idea on the best way]

Comment: Alternatively, you can use a drop-down menu similar to Amazon.com or eBay.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I knew I had seen this before but here was an example of how Microsoft handled it.  Pretty straightforward.  There might be a prettier way to design the icon though.  :)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively– a you mention price as another "column"– you could integrate the sorting buttons into the list itself similar to a sortable table. Unless the objective is to enable sort hierarchies (e.g. by name, then price).

[image: Table sort]

Comment: I think the column based is the best. It's pretty well assumed that first comes index, and by clicking any column header, the list gets sorted first by low-to-high (a-z), and by clicking that column again, high-to-low (z-a). It's what I prefer any day of the week.

Comment: I don't use a table, so clicking 'columns' are not useful to me, I use a horizontally scrolling list, but thanks for the suggestion.